# Out of Office reply set in Outlook being overwritten by old reply

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, outlook, outlook-2003, email

We are using Exchange 2007 on a Windows Server 2008 machine.

We have to log into OWA and delete the Out of Office reply there in order to be able to change it in Outlook.  If we do not do this and try to change it in Outlook (2003), it simply reverts back to the old reply.  I have never seen this before and have been unable to find any information on it anywhere.

This problem is affecting two different users, has only started happening recently and there have been no Microsoft Updates installed on the server since December's patch Tuesday.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just searching around... I [found](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/exchangesvrclients/thread/069d73ee-1603-4818-adea-06d3d9885bd6) this suggestion for someone else who was having the same issue

Go to Start -> Run -> Type in Outlook /cleanserverrules -> Click Ok